# Extracting only visitors' post from a Facebook page

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, text-analysis

I want to extract only the visitors' posts of a Facebook page. I am using Rfacebook package.

```
posts -> getPage(page="Troll.Football",token=access_token, feed=T)
```

This command provides the admin posts too. How can I filter out the admin posts?

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: the library doesn't seem to allow for that, the only option seems to be post-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the help files, the easiest option seems to be filtering out after retrieval. Here are some examples on how to do that:

```
posts <- getPage(page="Troll.Football",token=access_token, feed=T)
subset(posts, from_name != "Troll Football")
#or
posts[posts$from_name != "Troll Football",]
```

Comment: Yeah I also did the same in the end